# append a digit to variable in a loop + javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

> var count = document.getElementById("button_id").value

```
for (var i=1;i<=count;i++) 
{ 
 var client"#{i}" = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button'#{i}'") 
 client"#{i}".on( "load", function(client"#{i}") {} 
}
```

The lines in the loop are in RoR, 
it evaluates into

```
var client1 = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button1") 
client1.on( "load", function(client1) {}
```

and so on ..

How to get this in done in `JS`

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. I think you just need to find a different approach.

Comment: Have you written the loop in erb file ???

Comment: then what actually you want to do??

Comment: the loop is in Rails, how to get in JS, `"#{i}"` equivalent in js ?